# "no tests have been done" or "no test has been done"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Should I say "no tests have been done" or "no test has been done" in case when only one test could possibly be done?

For example, in the case of a director who entered an empty classroom where a reportedly lazy teacher works, he may report to the principle as:

> I've checked all her papers. The tests on papers 1 through 5 have been done, however, **no tests
>   have been done on paper 6 yet**

So, here the plural "no tests have been done" is used because there are more than one students in the class.

However, if it's one of those student's parent writing a complaint about that lazy teacher to the principal, then could he/she write something like:

> It's been already quite a long time since my daughter's progress has
>   been tested. The tests on papers 1 through 5 were done long time ago.
>   And **no test has been done on paper 6 yet**

?

Comment: A correction to the English in one part of your question, as it’s also to do with plurals: it should be “there is more than one student in the class” rather than “there are more than one students in the class”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be “no test has been done” in both cases, because there is only one test per paper. The number of test recipients is irrelevant.

Comment: What if it were two tests per paper?

Comment: Then “no tests have been done” would make the most sense

Answer (score 0):

...That's rather unidiomatic, phrasing it like that. Better would probably be "there hasn't been a test" for a test that hasn't occured, or "the test hasn't been graded" for a test that hasn't been marked yet. In all cases, all the versions of the test and every individual test paper are regarded as a singular "test", although sometimes it makes sense to say "I graded your tests" when there was only one test.